# Interacting with Dataproc Serverless using Dataproc Client Library

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-dataproc-serverless

I'm writing a java code in which I run `Spark batches` using `Dataproc Serverless`. I have initially used `Dataproc Client Library` for java and so far, it works just fine. However, by looking at `Dataproc Serverless` documentation (https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless/docs), there is not a single mention of interacting with it by using Java Client - it mentions REST, RPC and Cloud SDK.

I started wondering if I'm doing something wrong. Is using `Dataproc Client Library` for `Dataproc Serverless` related actions actually not recommended or somehow limited?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it right - the Dataproc Client Library is the correct library to interact with Dataproc Serverless (for context, it uses the gRPC API mentioned in the Dataproc Serverless documentation). Generally, Dataproc Serverless is a part of the overall Dataproc product. The fact that the Dataproc Client Library is not mentioned on the Dataproc Serverless docs page is a mistake.